# Is there a way to implement .net like attributes on a c++/cx ref class?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Wondering if there is a way to implement attributes on a c++/cx ref class in a way that resembles .net attributes. I tried to inherit from the `Platform::Metadata::Attribute` class which is an abstract class that other WinRT attributes inherit from. But all I get are compiler errors when I attempt to use the attribute.

Comment: Well C++/CX already *is* .NET, I think you mean attributes the way C# does it?

Comment: Sure. I was unaware that c++/cx was .net

Comment: C++/CX is not .NET, it is Windows Runtime.

Comment: That is what I thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use existing attributes but you cannot create any new attribute types. This is limitation of WinRT. A quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755822.aspx):

> **Attributes**
>
> An attribute is a metadata value that can be applied to any Windows Runtime type or type member and can be inspected at run time. The Windows Runtime defines a set of common attributes in the Windows::Foundation::Metadata namespace. **User-defined attributes on public interfaces are not supported by Windows Runtime in this release.**

Comment: Thanks. I was not able to find that on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Neither WinRT nor C++/CX support attributes.  The only reason the Platform::Metadata::Attribute namespace exists at all is because they can appear in .winmd files.  Which are the metadata files that a compiler can use to read the declarations for WinRT definitions written in another language.  Which would be of use only to such a compiler or an object browser, like the one in Visual Studio.  A .winmd file is created from an .idl file, very similar to the way it was done in COM and type libraries.  Or generated by a compiler.

There are only two such attributes.  DefaultAttribute corresponds with the [default] IDL attribute, FlagsAttribute corresponds with [flags].  They are not yet documented on MSDN, WinRT docs are generally very lacking.  [default] existed previously but got a new meaning.  [flags] is new, means the same thing it does in .NET.  You can see lots of examples of these two attributes in use in the *.idl files in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt directory on your machine.

Something else you can see from those IDL files is that WinRT doesn't actually support method overloads, generics, implementation inheritance or exceptions.  They are features added by the language projection.  At its core, WinRT is still a *lot* like COM of old.  Just lots of clever code in the tooling that hides this.  Like C++/CX does.  Also the core reason that Javascript can directly call C++, even though their runtime implementations are drastically different.  The required glue is very thin.